# How to make scrollview to pass touch event to the superview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uistackview

I am trying to create a `UITableViewCell` which has a horizontally scrollable `UIScrollView`. How to make sure that when user touches on the `UIScrollView`, the `UITableViewCell` gets selected.

The `UITableViewCell` has a `UIScrollView` as a subview as well as some other subviews. When user taps on non-`UIScrollView` subviews, the cell gets selected as expected.
However, when user taps on the `UIScrollView`, nothing happens.

The `UIScrollView` has some sub views. The user can horizontally scroll the scrollview as expected.

Is there any way such that, when user flicks through the `UIScrollView`, the `UIScrollView` handles the touch event, but when user taps on the `UIScrollView`, it passes the event to the superview?

Edit - 
I tried overriding [`touchesEnded(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621084-touchesended) as follows -

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    superview?.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

It did not work

Secondly, I tried adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the scrollview and check if detects the taps.
It does detect the tap. However, in order to select the `UITableViewCell`, I need to get the respective `UITableViewCell` for the scrollview, find its indexPath and then using the `UITableView` select that indexPath.

I am hoping if there is a simpler way to perform what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you try adding a tap gesture? Did you try overriding `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` to detect tap? What did you try?

Comment: @Brandon, I have made an edit to my post, where I have listed what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the scrollView.

In the function that gets called when the user taps on the scrollview, I programmatically select the row as follows -

```
guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```